# Efficient way of finding points in a hexgrid

Tags: geojson, turfjs

I am displaying a 10km cell hexGrid overlay on a map (approx 1000km²).

I have a geoJSON file containing around 5000 coordinate points, along with a 'score' value for each point. I want to collect all the points that fall into each hex cell, and modify the cell colour based on the average of the score for all points in that cell.

My (simplified) code is as follows:

```
let map = L.map('map')
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map)

let hexgrid = turf.hexGrid(mapBound, cellSize, options)
L.geoJson(hexgrid, {onEachFeature: onEachHex}).addTo(map)

function onEachHex(feature, layer) {
  // find all points within this hex
  let found = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(pointsData, turf.polygon(feature.geometry.coordinates))
  // hexStyle defines a colour from the average scores in 'found' properties
  layer.setStyle(hexStyle)
}
```

The problem I am having is that with a 10km cell size, there are several thousand cells, and there are 5000 points to evaluate for each hex. This obviously takes a very long time to render.

Can anyone suggest a better way of achieving this? The best option I can think of so far is to throw away the `found` points from `pointsData` each time, but I don't fancy trying to unpick the geoJson manually to achieve this!

Any tips greatly appreciated!